# Ruby on Rails - Join two tables add results to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

New to Ruby on Rails 4.0 and I am having some trouble getting my JSON to add the data from my joined table. I am using AngularJS on the front end, and I can't seem to find a good example on here to help me out.

In short, I have a Invite with a User ID. I have a User with a User ID. Knowing the Invite ID, I want to get the name of the User that corresponds to that invite.

```
Invite 1: UserID: 10
Invite 2: UserID: 11
Invite 3: UserID: 12

UserID: 10 Name: Owen
UserID: 11 Name Greg
```

Controller - Invites

```
# GET /invites/1
# GET /invites/1.json
def show
   @invite = Invite.includes(:user).find(params[:id]).to_json(include: :user)
end
```

Model - Invite

```
class Invite < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_one :meal
has_one :event
has_one :registry
end
```

Model - User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :invite
end
```

However I only get this whenever I check the /invites/1.

```
{"id":1,"created_at":"2013-12-06T20:14:39.001Z","updated_at":"2013-12-06T20:58:15.597Z","event_id":7,"meal_id":8,"registry_id":0,"rsvp":false,"user_id":9}
```

Any help here is much appreciated!

Comment: How is this related to Angular?

Comment: @stewie I am using Angular on the front end, hoping to have someone familiar with ROR + Angular help me out.

Comment: Still, your question, per se, has nothing to do with Angular and has everything to do with Rails and DB. As such it absolutely does not deserve `angularjs` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your show should be:

```
def show
    @invite = Invite.includes(:user).find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => @invite.to_json(include: :user) }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use JBuilder http://rubygems.org/gems/jbuilder . You can use @invite.to_json, but JBuilder gives you much more control on the output.